# Raster with wrong extents when using Polygon to Raster

Tags: raster, arcmap, polygon, extents, rasterization

I am trying to use the "Polygon to Raster" tool on a building extents polygon file  to create a raster with the exact extents and cell size as an existing flood depth raster. Even though I have added my desired raster extent in the snap raster option in the Environment settings and defined the cell size, the result does not have the same extents. Furthermore, I made sure that they have the same projection (WGS_1984_UTM). I really need them to have the same extents and cell size as I want to do some calculations between them (e.g. calculate the flood depth at the buildings location). Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you set the coordinate systems up correctly / identical?

Comment: You should try and only ask one question per post and your extra question will also be almost impossible to answer.

Comment: Allan, yes they both have the same projection. BERA, I am sorry for the 2nd question. It is my first post and I was not that familiar with the rules. I have edited my post and removed the extra question.

Comment: Are you trying to copy a raster or convert a polygon-based feature class into a raster? Can you edit your question and include the extents, coordinate systems, other metadata plus screenshots of part of the layers so we can see what's happening?

Comment: arcpy.env.extent = r'c:\your\existing\raster' (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000), setting snapraster (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/) and cellsize just ensures the cell boundaries align by using an existing origin. What calculations need them to be precisely the same size?

Comment: Michael your answer made me realize that I did something stupid. When assigning the environment settings, I was only choosing the snap raster option and not the extents, as I thought that only one option should be used. When I used both of them, using my desired raster to define the extents and the snap raster it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that to have the rasterized polygons with the same extents and cell size, you have to both choose the desired raster as the extents AND as the snap raster. This resulted in a raster with the exact same extents and cell size as the desired one.